# Xamarin and .NET2 Shared project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xamarin

I have 1 project which may run as Winforms App(.NET 2) or as a Xamarin App or as WPF app. The business logic is the same and I would like to share the code between the Xamarin App and the Winforms App. In .NET 2.0 I don't have portable class libraries and in Xamarin I cannot add .NET 2.0 project.

I thought it would be a chance to use an API and use it as shared code(WCF not available in 2.0). Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the code that is used by mulitple project into a `Shared Project`. In the other projects you have to reference this `Shared Project`.

## The solution should look like

[image]

The last project is the `Shared Project`

## The project's references should look like:

Right click on `References` and click `Add Reference` and the select `Shared Projects` tab and select the shared project you created

[image]

Comment: Will the SharedProject work in a .NET2 environment? Between WPF and Xamarin it works for sure, but the issue is with the .NET2

Comment: @DragoshStoica Yes